# arguments to invoke mule callable oncall method

Tags: java, mule, mule-studio

I'm trying to call a class which implements Callable from a Java Invoke in Mule. But I cannot figure out what to pass as method arguments from the invoke configuration. Please help!

```
public class ModificationService implements Callable {
@Override
public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
    MuleMessage msg = eventContext.getMessage();
    String path = msg.getProperty("destination", PropertyScope.OUTBOUND);
    String[] splitpath = path.split("/");
    path = splitpath[0];
    msg.setProperty("destination", path, PropertyScope.OUTBOUND);

    MuleMessage newMessage = new DefaultMuleMessage(path, msg, eventContext.getMuleContext());

    return newMessage;
}
```

Configuration XML

```
<invoke name="ModificationBean" object-ref="modificationServiceBean" method="onCall" methodArguments="#[payload]" doc:name="Invoke"/>
```

I have passed message payload just for the sake of not keeping the argument part empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the class that you created will work for Java Component of mule since you will need a reference to MuleEventContext, where you can get the value of the payload.

See this link:

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/java-component-reference

While what you are looking for is this:

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/invoke-component-reference

You will need to create a custom class, see example below:

The addTwoNumbers is the class method where is has #[1] and #[2] as the arguments. Those can be flowVars or SessionVars or payload.

Comment: I see.. Is there a way to manipulate flowVars or sessionVars using Java component? Because I want to keep the payload intact

Comment: onCall method: String payload = eventContext.getMessage().getPayload().toString();
  // To get the variables
  String nameOfFlowVar = eventContext.getMessage().getProperty("nameOfFlowVar", PropertyScope.INVOCATION).toString();
  // To get the variables
  String nameOfSessionVar = eventContext.getMessage().getProperty("nameOfSessionVar", PropertyScope.SESSION).toString();
  // To update the variables
  eventContext.getMessage().setProperty("nameOfFlowVar", "SomeValue",PropertyScope.INVOCATION);
  eventContext.getMessage().setProperty("nameOfSessionVar", "SomeValue", PropertyScope.INVOCATION);

Comment: Try to paste that inside the onCall method where you have the reference of eventContext.

Answer (score 0):

This could be help you:

"How set/get variables, manipulate or modify the payload, read properties file and spring in the same java component"

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32612487/3957754

https://github.com/jrichardsz/mule-esb-usefull-templates

Simple component with callable method:

```
package com.spring.component;

import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import org.mule.api.MuleEventContext;
import org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.mule.api.transport.PropertyScope;

@Component("myComponent")
@Scope("prototype")

/*
 * Use Callable if you want : 
 * (spring functionalities, handle mule message and read a properties file) 
 * at the same time.
 * */
public class MyComponent implements Callable{

//  @Autowired
//  private AnotherSpringComponetOrServiceOrWhatever spring;    

    @Override
    public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {

        //get payload
        String payload = (String) eventContext.getMessage().getPayload();

        //SESSION, INBOUND, OUTBOUND, APPLICATION
        //http://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/anypoint-platform-dev/mule-school-the-mulemessage-property-scopes-and-variables/

        //get vars according to its scope
        String inputProperty = eventContext.getMessage().getProperty("inputProperty", PropertyScope.INVOCATION);

        //set vars in some scope
        eventContext.getMessage().setProperty("key", "some_value", PropertyScope.SESSION);

        //return eventContext.getMessage().getPayload(); //payload is intact
        return "NEW_PAYLOAD";
    }

}
```

In mule flow with spring:

```
<component doc:name="myComponent">
    <spring-object bean="myComponent" />
</component>
```

Or without spring (delete spring annotations )

```
<component class="com.spring.component.MyComponent" doc:name="MyComponent"/>
```

I hope this helps you.